# Extracting data from multiple files using Pentaho

Tags: transformation, pentaho

I am trying to create a transformation that will extract data from multiple files and upload to a database. On the database, I have a table with 2 fields containing a source name and the file path. I need to extract the filepath from the records and pass the information to a step to extract the data and upload to a result table. I am able to do it for a single record but am not able to do it for multiple records. Is there a way to implement a loop to read the records and extract the data.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Unfortunately I followed the steps and it works fine as long as there is only one input file. Whereas with 2 or more files, it breaks down. Also, whatever I am trying to do is to pull data from multiple files with varying number of columns but of same file formats.

Comment: If the format of your files are different, you'll need to look at the `ETL Metadata Injection` step.

Answer (score 1):

Most file based PDI input steps allow you to "accept filename from previous step". If your input is coming from the same type of file (just a lot of them), this should suit your needs.

You never said if the files are all the same type or what type that is, so I'm going to assume they are all the same type and that type is CSV/TXT, since that's the most common case in my experience.

That being the case, add a `Table input` step and select the contents of your table that has the filenames. Connect that to a `Text file input step` and check the `Accept filenames from previous steps` checkbox. Then choose the name of your table input in the `Step to read filenames from` box, and select field name in the `Field in the input to use as filename` box.

Then go ahead and configure the text file input based on your file format. That should do it as long as all your files conform to the same format.

If any of my assumptions are incorrect, let me know via comment and we'll see what we can do.